# Predictor-Corrector vs. Deferred Difference Corrections

Tags: finite-difference

I want to use the Numerov method but keep higher-order terms from the Taylor expansions. In the literature, I found the term "Deferred Difference Corrections" for the procedure of first solving the differential equations via the standard Numerov method and afterward adding the higher-order terms. For me, this sounds just like a Predictor-Corrector method. Can someone tell me what the difference is?